# Android Studio: there is a Exclamation mark in SDK Update Sites

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-2.3

When I open the Android SDK in Android Studio:

```
Name                                             URL
!Glass Development Kit, Google Inc               https://dl-ssl.google.com/glass/gdk/addon.xml
```

---

Now I wanna to know this "!" before the `Glass Development Kit, Google Inc`，does it impact my project?

Comment: [Does it look like this?](https://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=1996270000000&name=Red_Explanation_Android_Repository.png&token=ABZ6GAeFN9LKWByKoTHEog5c3khR4Me5wQ%3A1457321152553&id=199627&mod_ts_token=ABZ6GAd-Kt7aSF1IZNydaPdgrCYcJZmpyQ%3A1457321152553&inline=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199627) was reported recently, describing the same problem that you're having, and from what's said on that thread, it looks like it was fixed already.

If you're using Android Studio 2.0 preview, that's most likely your problem.

[image: Red exclamation]

**Try to update your Android Studio** and it should disappear.

By the way, it doesn't seems to be a problem at all, even if you don't update, it should work just fine.